# getting a longer part of a first chance exception handler message (in VS2008)?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, exception

I need to see more of the `First-chance exception` message as presented in Visual Studio.
Is there amethod for getting a longer message, or am I misunderstanding the message.

> First-chance exception at 0x7c812afb in SenseToAvoid.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x03f7fc30..

It's the final double dot `..` that makes me think there is more information to be had. I'm using VS2008 pro.

Comment: I was wondering about that, too.